# Multiple image not saved to its foreign key object

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-1.9

I have created a form using frontend view library where user get to upload multiple images. I could develop it but the images are not saved to its associated rent. For this i have to manually assign rent from admnin.

[image: mannually assigned from admin(this is what i am wanting but not through admin.It should be automatically populate when uploaded)]

[image: But images are saved like this. They are not associated with its rent when they are uploaded]

**Models.py**

```
class Rental(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Owner's Name"),max_length=255, blank=True,null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=120,blank=True,null=True)

class GalleryImage(models.Model):
    rental = models.ForeignKey('Rental',on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True,
                                verbose_name=_('Rental'), related_name="gallery")
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True,upload_to='upload/',null=True)
```

**views.py for image upload**

```
class UploadImage(View):
    model = Rental
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        if request.FILES:
            for file in request.FILES.getlist('image'):
                print('file',file)
                # rental = request.POST.get('rental', False)
                # print('rental is', rental)
                image = GalleryImage.objects.create(image=file)
                image.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

class AddView(TemplateView): // upload form is in add.html template
    template_name = 'rentals/add.html'
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^add/$', AddView.as_view(), name="add"),
url(r'^upload/image/$', UploadImage.as_view(), name="uploadImage"),
```

**addrent.js(ajax code for multiple image upload)**

```
var image = [];
image = new FormData(files);
$.each(files,function(i,file){
  image.append('image',file);
});
$.ajax({
    url:"/upload/image/",
    data:image,
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    type:'POST',
    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('success');
    }
});
}
```

What i have to do to save multiple images to their associated rental instance like the first image ?

Comment: I don't get the way you're creating the object, you use "create", why not instantiating the object with all the parameters and than simply save it? And besides that, the parameter for rental is not explicitly passed to the server (as far as i can see from the code you posted). Can you show the template?

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the id of the rental object somehow (in URL path or in URL GET parameters). Then in the view you need to fetch the object and when you create `GalleryImage` object to pass it as argument.

Also you don't need to call `image.save()` after `objects.create()`. It's already in the database.